# QTP : How to add a Java list into my object repository

Tags: java, qtp

I am facing an issue when adding a JAVA list into my object repository.
In fact while spying I click on the scrollable button (maintaining CTRL button) the JAVA list is displayed in  the object tree as soon as I want to go back to my object repository to add the Java List the list is not displayed any more and therefore I am not able to add it.
Do you have any idea on how I can overcome this issue.

Thanks
Zied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Object Repository Manager´s "Navigate and Learn" feature for this.** Hopefully.

From the main menu, select Resources/Object Repository Manager. Then, select "Navigate and learn", select your app´s window, and click "Learn", then "close". The result is an object repo manager with all objects from the GUI.

There are some applications (i.e. GUIs), that are not really 100% compatible with what QTP expects. **My rule of thumb is "If 'Navigate & learn' cannot catch this, it´s not worth to be considered".**

It is highly inconsistent that Navigate & learn discovers GUI facts that are left unobserved by spy, btw. I consider this a bug.